# subquery returned more than one result error

Tags: sql-server

I'm converting an MSAccess based application (+VB Code) to a web application. The database stays the same in the process, this access app used handful of stored procedures.

Below code execute a stored procedure.

```
Dim prmJ_YearSeq_pk As ADODB.Parameter
Set cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
cmd1.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
cmd1.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd1.CommandText = "sp_delete_from_t_Job_and_t_Report"
Set prmJ_YearSeq_pk = 
    cmd1.CreateParameter("@J_YearSeq_pk", adInteger, adParamInput)
cmd1.Parameters.Append prmJ_YearSeq_pk
prmJ_YearSeq_pk.Value = Me.J_YearSeq_pk
cmd1.Execute
```

Now when execute the same stored procedure from SQL Management Studio

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_delete_from_t_Job_and_t_Report]
        @J_YearSeq_pk = 20110001
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

It throws an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

What I don't understand is, why it works just fine in the Access App but not in Management Studio or my web app (PHP PDO)?

Comment: You need to supply the definition of `sp_delete_from_t_Job_and_t_Report`. Presumably somewhere that has a sub query returning more than one row where a scalar is expected.

Comment: Some older databases just use the first row when multiple rows are returned by what is supposed to be a scalar query. When using a more standards compliant database the query has to be re-written to only return one row.